# How do I show the line number and source file of an error in SBCL?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

My `~/.sbclrc` looks like this:

```
(sb-ext:restrict-compiler-policy 'debug 3)

(setf *debugger-hook* #'(lambda (condition original-hook)
                          (declare (ignore original-hook))
                          (print-backtrace)
                          (format *error-output* "~%~A~%" condition)
                          (finish-output *error-output*)
                          (abort)))
```

Suppose I have a program `my-program.lisp` containing a bad function:

```
;; ...
(defun calculate (x)
  (/ x 0))
;; ...
```

If I run:

```
$ sbcl --load my-program.lisp
* (calculate 100)
```

I get this error:

```
Backtrace for: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005E85B3}>
0: (SB-KERNEL::INTEGER-/-INTEGER 100 0)
1: (CALCULATE 100)
2: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (CALCULATE 100) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
3: (EVAL (CALCULATE 100))
4: (INTERACTIVE-EVAL (CALCULATE 100) :EVAL NIL)
5: (SB-IMPL::REPL-FUN NIL)
6: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-REPL))
7: (SB-IMPL::%WITH-REBOUND-IO-SYNTAX #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-REPL) {10046268FB}>)
8: (SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-REPL NIL)
9: (SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-INIT)
10: ((FLET SB-UNIX::BODY :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))
11: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-36" :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))
12: ((LABELS SB-IMPL::RESTART-LISP :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))

arithmetic error DIVISION-BY-ZERO signalled
Operation was (/ 100 0).
```

But where is the line number and the source file of the runtime error? Imagine if I have hundreds of files, and thousands of functions. Wouldn't it be helpful to know the file, the line number, and the column number of the error? How do I show the line number and source file of the error?

I am surprised that this programming language does not have this feature by default when just about all other interpreters and compilers are able to do this easily.

Comment: A [new discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Common_Lisp/comments/nho1f5/stack_backtraces_line_numbers/) with a pointer to [bissect](https://shinmera.github.io/dissect/) which "can provide line number information for you if provided by the implementation."

Answer (score 3):

I typically use SLIME + GNU Emacs with SBCL.

I then compile/load a file with debug level 3.

Then I can press `v` in the backtrace window on a frame and the editor jumps to the source code.

Answer (score 3):

Working from Slime (or Sly) gives this feature out of the box, but in fact this is made possible because the underlying environment already stores enough information. If you look at how the code is implemented (by navigating with <kbd>`M-.`</kbd> in Emacs, you can see that in SBCL, source code location depends partly from `sb-introspect`.

In your example, after loading the file that contains `calculate`, if you `require` this module, as follows:

```
* (require 'sb-introspect)
("SB-INTROSPECT")
```

You can find all the relevant information by calling `find-definition-source`:

```
* (sb-introspect:find-definition-source #'calculate)
#S(SB-INTROSPECT:DEFINITION-SOURCE
   :PATHNAME #P"/tmp/mp.lisp"
   :FORM-PATH (2)
   :FORM-NUMBER 0
   :CHARACTER-OFFSET 51
   :FILE-WRITE-DATE 3817139822
   :PLIST NIL
   :DESCRIPTION NIL)
```

In addition to the file, SBCL also stores the location as character offsets, but also the number of forms in that file (so if you add whitespaces or comments in front of it, the editor can still find it location even after the file is modified).

The backtrace printer function also have options to have more or less information.

Comment: `#'sb-introspect:find-definition-source` provides the character offset, but is there a way to obtain the **line number**?

Comment: @Flux the line number only matters if you're using an editor which can't move to a character offset in a file, or you're debugging using hard copy.  I've done both of those things, but it was a long time ago now.